# upload video stream and audio stream on iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

Here's the needs: People record their video via my App and upload stream to our website, you know, like a live show.

When they are recording, the network goes bad, then record audio instead of video.
And when audience watch, first comes the video, in a certain time comes the audio with a static picture.

How am I supposed to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this after thinking. So I'll answer by my self.

If you wanna record video and audio separately. Use lower level Library to handle this. Then upload it. And you can get the upload speed, When the speed goes low, you can shut down the video upload process.